# Unfamiliar C syntax?

Tags: c, libuv

I am trying to understand C code written by others and have come across a piece of code that I  do not understand all of the syntax and the parts I don't understand I don't know how to search for. I would appreciate either an explanation or information on how to search this and other similar things I may encounter, or both. The code in question is the following line:

```
int r = uv_listen((uv_stream_t*) &server, 128, on_new_connection);
```

I understand that r is a variable that is being declared and initialized to the value returned by the function "uv_listen()", 128 is a literal int paramater, on_new_connection has to be a function pointer since that is the name of a call back function that is called. server is a variable of a custom type (uv_tcp_t) and with the & it is referring to the address of server. What I don't understand is the "(uv_stream_t*) &server". It looks like this is one of the parameters to the function. I could understand a function call that returned a value as a parameter but this doesn't look like a function call. "uv_stream_t" is another custom type that is defined in their code.

I don't know if it is helpful in understanding what it means but the line of code is from sample code written to help in understanding how to use libuv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a type cast. `&server` gives the address of the `server` variable and `(uv_stream_t*)` casts the type of that address.

Based on the other information in your post, it seems that `server` is of type `uv_tcp_t`, but `uv_listen` wants a pointer to `uv_stream_t`. That's why you take the address of `server` and cast it to `uv_stream_t*`.

Note: this only makes sense because of how libuv defines `uv_tcp_t` and `uv_server_t` — in general you can't just cast pointer types to other pointer types and expect anything reasonable to happen.

Answer (score 2):

(uv_stream_t*) &server is taking the server address and casting it to a uv_stream pointer.

&server - take address of server

(uv_stream*) - cast to uv_stream pointer

Answer (score 0):

It's a type cast operator, used to tell the compiler to accept &server as a pointer to a uv_stream_t.

Presumably the type of 'server' is not uv_stream_t or a subclass, but the coder knows that it's safe to be treated as one.